# Newtonsoft.Json throws an exception inside RestEase

Tags: api, asp.net-core, json.net, resteasy

I'm getting such exception

```
JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

I'm using RestEase(https://github.com/canton7/RestEase) with such interface

```
public interface ISomeApi
{
    [Get("{version}/data/count")]
    Task<SomeResult> GetCount(
        [Path] string version,
        [Query("metaType")] string metaType,
        [Query("query", QuerySerializationMethod.Serialized)] QueryParams queryParams);
}
```

My query param model

```
public class QueryParams
{
    [JsonProperty("foo")]
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bar")]
    public string Bar{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bass")]
    public string Bass{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("boom")]
    public string Boom{ get; set; }
}
```

Why do I get this exception? What done wrong?

I was trying to avoid using `QueryParams` and just used `string` where I passed already converted to string representation json model, but got the same exception. Also I tried to escape json specific symbols, but it didn't help.

Comment: Is the data you are trying to parse actually JSON?  The error indicates that the first character is a `<`,  which means that it is probably XML (or HTML).  JSON starts with `{` or `[`.

Comment: @BrianRogers, yes, it wasn't json format.